# Merge Columns In R with NA values

Tags: r

Im looking to merge columns in a data frame and generate a new column to identify the new value

Currently

```
  Sample              Temp1  Temp2  Temp3    
    1      A          121.3  NA     NA
    2      B           NA    35.1   NA
    3      C           NA    NA     39.9
```

Desired Output

```
  Sample              Temp  Reading   
    1      A          121.3 Temp 1
    2      B          35.1  Temp 2
    3      C          39.9  Temp 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and specify that you want to drop NAs.

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, -Sample, names_to = "Temp", values_to = "Reading", values_drop_na = TRUE)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Sample Temp  Reading
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 A      Temp1   121. 
#> 2 B      Temp2    35.1
#> 3 C      Temp3    39.9
```

---

`df` is defined as

```
df <- read.table(text = " Sample              Temp1  Temp2  Temp3    
    1      A          121.3  NA     NA
    2      B           NA    35.1   NA
    3      C           NA    NA     39.9  ", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This solution has worked. However i just realized there is some smaples with two temps in one line.  
df <- read.table(text = " Sample              Temp1  Temp2  Temp3    
    1      A          121.3  35.1     NA
    2      B           NA    35.1   NA
    3      C           NA    NA     39.9  ", header = TRUE)

Comment: how can i edit the origianl data frame to split out the sample with two value before applying the solution
df <- read.table(text = " Sample              Temp1  Temp2  Temp3    
    1      A          121.3     NA  NA
    2      B           NA     35.1   NA
    3      C           NA    35.1   NA
    4      D           NA    NA     39.9  ", header = TRUE)

Comment: what is your expected output? even with two values, the output with my solution looks actionable to me.

Comment: thhe df above is part of a larger data frame with more info. when i run the code it does give the desired output with 4 columns . however the rest of the data frame has only the original 3 columns so i cannot replace the new output into the larger data frame.

Comment: If your case is more complicated than what you showed, you should have written a different sample and a different expected output. :-) now, try this: instead of `-Sample` use `starts_with("Temp")` or just write a vector of the variables you want to gather up. Do this on your original data. The values of the other columns will be ignored by `pivot_longer` and copied when necessary.

Comment: i didnt this this would be an issue. if i start fresh. the data frame i have is 
df <- read.table(text = " Sample              Temp1  Temp2  Temp3 Result   
    1      A          121.3  35.1     NA  Fail
    2      B           NA    35.1   NA Pass 
    3      C           NA    NA     39.9  Pass ", header = TRUE)

desired output is 
    Sample      Temp   Reading   Result   
1     A            Temp 1   121.3 Fail
2     A            Temp 1     35.1 Fail
3     B            Temp 2      35.1Pass
4     C           Temp 3      39.9 Pass

Comment: do you think that `pivot_longer(df, starts_with("Temp"), names_to = "Temp", values_to = "Reading", values_drop_na = TRUE)` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One option

```
tmp <- grep("Temp", colnames(df))

df["Temp"] <- rowSums(df[tmp], na.rm = T)
df["Reading"] <- paste0("Temp ", which(!is.na(df[tmp]), arr.ind = T)[, 2])

  Sample Temp1 Temp2 Temp3  Temp Reading
1      A 121.3    NA    NA 121.3  Temp 1
2      B    NA  35.1    NA  35.1  Temp 2
3      C    NA    NA  39.9  39.9  Temp 3
```